# Open GL ES 2.0 Rendering

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0, render

I'm having an issue where I have an open GL ES 2.0 based view that first draws to a texture and then renders that texture to the screen.

I instantiate this view as a subview of a main UIView with other buttons. The texture for some reason doesn't render immediately when drawn, rather only after one of the buttons is pressed.

Has anyone experienced anything like this? Thank you in advance
Uba Duba

Here is the drawing and rendering code:

```
// Drawings a line onscreen based on where the user touches
- (void)renderLineFromPoint:(CGPoint)start toPoint:(CGPoint)end
{
    static GLfloat*     vertexBuffer = NULL;
    static NSUInteger   vertexMax = 64;
    NSUInteger          vertexCount = 0,
    count,
    i;

    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbTemp);
    // Convert locations from Points to Pixels
    CGFloat scale = self.contentScaleFactor;
    start.x *= scale;
    start.y *= scale;
    end.x *= scale;
    end.y *= scale;

    // Allocate vertex array buffer
    if(vertexBuffer == NULL)
        vertexBuffer = malloc(vertexMax * 2 * sizeof(GLfloat));

    // Add points to the buffer so there are drawing points every X pixels
    count = MAX(ceilf(sqrtf((end.x - start.x) * (end.x - start.x) + (end.y - start.y) * (end.y - start.y)) / kBrushPixelStep), 1);
    for(i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        if(vertexCount == vertexMax) {
            vertexMax = 2 * vertexMax;
            vertexBuffer = realloc(vertexBuffer, vertexMax * 2 * sizeof(GLfloat));
        }

        vertexBuffer[2 * vertexCount + 0] = start.x + (end.x - start.x) * ((GLfloat)i / (GLfloat)count);
        vertexBuffer[2 * vertexCount + 1] = start.y + (end.y - start.y) * ((GLfloat)i / (GLfloat)count);
        vertexCount += 1;
    }

    // Load data to the Vertex Buffer Object
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboId);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexCount*2*sizeof(GLfloat), vertexBuffer, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(pointShader.positionLoc);
    glVertexAttribPointer(pointShader.positionLoc, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, brushTexture.id);
    // Draw
    glUseProgram(pointShader.programObject);

    // the brush texture will be bound to texture unit 0
    glUniform1i(pointShader.textureLoc, 0);

    // viewing matrices
    GLKMatrix4 projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeOrtho(0, backingWidth, 0, backingHeight, -1, 1);
    GLKMatrix4 modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Identity; // this sample uses a constant identity modelView matrix
    GLKMatrix4 MVPMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(projectionMatrix, modelViewMatrix);

    glUniformMatrix4fv(pointShader.MVPLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, MVPMatrix.m);

    // point size
    glUniform1f(pointShader.pointSizeLoc, brushTexture.width / kBrushScale);

    // initialize brush color
    glUniform4fv(pointShader.vertexColorLoc, 1, brushColor);

    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, vertexCount);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    [self drawResult];


}
```

and the drawResult function that does the rendering:

```
// Draw current result at the present render buffer.
- (void) drawResult
{

    NSLog(@"Calling Draw Result");

    // Bind the master frame buffer.
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbMaster);
    // Clear the buffer.
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Draw the background board.
    [self drawTexture:masterTexture ];
    // Draw the temporary (drawing) board.
    [self drawTexture:tempTexture];


    // Bind the render buffer and present it to the view's context.
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, renderBuffer);
    [context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
}
```

the draw texture function that binds the texture

```
// Draw a texture at the full screen quad
- (void) drawTexture:(GLuint) textureID
{
    // Positions to draw a texture at the full screen quad.
    const GLfloat vVerticesStraight[] = {
        -1.0f,  1, 0.0f,  // Position 0
        0.0f,  1.0f,        // TexCoord 0
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,  // Position 1
        0.0f,  0.0f,        // TexCoord 1
        1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,  // Position 2
        1.0f,  0.0f,        // TexCoord 2
        1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,  // Position 3
        1.0f,  1.0f         // TexCoord 3
    };

    // Index order for draw element.
    const GLushort indices[] = { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 };

    // Use the program object
    glUseProgram ( drawTexture.programObject );

    // Load the vertex position
    glVertexAttribPointer ( drawTexture.a_positionLoc, 3, GL_FLOAT,
                           GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat), vVerticesStraight );

    // Load the texture coordinate
    glVertexAttribPointer ( drawTexture.a_texCoordLoc, 2, GL_FLOAT,
                           GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat), &vVerticesStraight[3] );

    // Enable attribute for the vertex array.
    glEnableVertexAttribArray ( drawTexture.a_positionLoc );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray ( drawTexture.a_texCoordLoc );

    // Bind the texture.
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture ( GL_TEXTURE_2D,  textureID);
    glUniform1i ( drawTexture.s_textureLoc, 0 );

    // Draw the texture.
    glDrawElements ( GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indices );

    // Bind the current texture to the default texture.
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);


}
```

There is no background threading, what's very strange is the first drawing seems to render to the texture but not to the screen, but after pressing another button on the view, the texture renders to the screen.

Comment: Can you comment on whether you're attempting any threading, and/or whether you used GLKit or `CAOpenGLLayer`?

Comment: Most of such "delayed update" behaviors are caused by submitting changes in background threads. Have you create a opengl context on background thread? I've never tried that, so I'm not sure. Since you provided no code.

Comment: Hi, code has since been added, no threading, and I've used the CAOpenGLLayer, not GLKit